# How to write case for empty record in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am having two table

```
Employee 1
    Emp_Id  Name    Old_Id
    111     Hemant  1
    222     Sachin  2
```

Employee

```
Emp_ID  Name    Temp_Name
1       Hemant  NULL
2       Sachin  NULL
3       Vinod   NULL
4       Nitin   1
5       Ajit    2
6       Suraj   3
```

I want to replace Temp_Name in Employee table by its new value available in Employee1 table.

Employee.Temp_Name is Employee1.Old_Id

Condition

1 : if Temp_Name is not present in Employee1.Old_id column it should be retained.

2 : Without creating any function.

The final output should be :

Employee

```
Emp_ID  Name    Short_Name
1       Hemant  NULL
2       Sachin  NULL
3       Vinod   NULL
4       Nitin   111
5       Ajit    222
6       Suraj   3
```

I tried this

```
Update [Employee] 
set 
Temp_Name = (
select CASE Emp_ID  
       WHEN NULL THEN [Employee].Temp_Name
       ELSE Emp_ID
       END AS Emp_ID
from [Employee1] e1
where e1.old_id = [Employee].Temp_Name
)
```

But it gives me output :

Employee

```
Emp_ID  Name    Temp_Name
1       Hemant  NULL
2       Sachin  NULL
3       Vinod   NULL
4       Nitin   111
5       Ajit    222
6       Suraj   NULL
```

Comment: tag only the related database

Comment: How come Nitin short_name is 111 ?

Comment: @Backtrack : I update the question , i mentioned it now.

Comment: Really bad form to not put the flavor of SQL you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` with a combination of `CASE` expression.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dc286/1/0)

```
SELECT
    e.Emp_Id,
    e.Name,
    Short_Name = 
        CASE
            WHEN e1.Old_Id IS NOT NULL THEN e1.Emp_Id
            ELSE e.Short_Name
        END
FROM Employee e
LEFT JOIN Employee1 e1
    ON e1.Old_Id = e.Short_Name
```

*`UPDATE` statement*

```
UPDATE e
    SET e.Short_Name = e1.Emp_Id
FROM Employee e
LEFT JOIN Employee1 e1
    ON e1.Old_Id = e.Short_Name
WHERE e1.Old_Id IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This is for sql server.

Here's the code I have with inserting the sample data:

```
begin tran

    create table Employee1
    (
        Emp_Id int,
        Name varchar(50),
        Old_Id int
    );

    create table Employee
    (
        Emp_Id int,
        Name varchar(50),
        Short_Name int NULL
    );

    insert into Employee1
    values(111, 'Hemant', 1);

    insert into Employee1
    values(222, 'Sachin', 2);

    insert into Employee
    values(1, 'Hemant', NULL);

    insert into Employee
    values(2, 'Sachin', NULL);

    insert into Employee
    values(3, 'Vinod', NULL);

    insert into Employee
    values(4, 'Nitin', 1);

    insert into Employee
    values(5, 'Ajit', 2);

    insert into Employee
    values(6, 'Suraj', 3);

    update emp
    set
        emp.Short_Name = CASE 
                            WHEN emp1.Emp_Id IS NULL THEN emp.Short_Name
                            ELSE emp1.Emp_Id
                        END
    from
        Employee emp
        left join Employee1 emp1
            on (emp.Short_Name = emp1.Old_Id)

    select * From Employee

    drop table Employee1
    drop table Employee

rollback
```

You had to ensure you left join your tables.